# Highcharts: tickInterval on coloraxis

Tags: highcharts

I cannot set up tickInterval values below 1 - it always defaults to 1 as the minimum step. See http://jsfiddle.net/L3W3N/1/

```
    colorAxis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
        tickInterval: 0.5,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
```

Setting tickInterval to 0.5 or 0.25 makes no difference.

Since the heatmap range is {-1, 1}, I would like to set tickInterval for the coloraxis to something like 0.5 or 0.25.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tickPositions` property which allows you to manually override the `tickInterval`  http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.tickPositions

e.g.

```
colorAxis: {
            min: -1,
            max: 1,
            tickPositions: [-1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1],
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/L3W3N/3/